# Installing 64 bit Ubuntu on HP Mini 110

Tags: 64-bit, intel-atom

I'm trying to install 64 bit Ubuntu on an HP Mini 110, with 2GB of RAM and a N2600 64bit capable Atom CPU, due to a requirement to install software that is available in 64 bit only.

However, possibly due to a restriction in the BIOS, I'm unable to install the 64 bit OS, since the installer reports that the machine in not 64 bit capable.

Comment: It appears the BIOS may indeed be crippling your system.  See answers to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/433753/this-cpu-is-not-compatible-with-64-bit-mode-installing-windows-7-ultimate-6

Comment: I have seen questions on this site about 64 bit processors with 32 bit BIOS and how to install on them, but they were Macs IIRC.  Don't remember seeing a reference to a Compaq Mini like this.

Comment: Are there any BIOS updates available on the HP Support site for your model? It's possible the issue has been addressed in newer BIOS versions

Comment: @OrganicMarble you are most likely to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

My Hp 1103 came with Win 7 Pro and 2GB ram - from the factory!!!!
In my BIOS there is an option to enable 64-bit architecture.
These models were made in small numbers toward the end of the 1103 production life.
But they sure exist - I have one and I now run Windows 10 Pro.
Not a speed demon to be sure - but very adequate.